# Why execution of the same program is a lot faster after the first time

Tags: c, caching

I'm working on a C program (Ubuntu 14.04) that does basically:

- Opens a 1GB file
- Reads it by buffer of 1MB
- Looks for some objects in the buffer
- Computes the MD5 signature of each object found

My program take 10 secondes the first time to achieve this, and then only 1 seconde the next times (even if I work on a second copy of initial file).

I know that this has something to do with caching, does my program work on cached data after the first time ? or directly show cached results without doing any computation ?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
unsigned char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int i, number, count = 0;
int start, end = 0;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("/dump/ram.lime", "r");
if (file != NULL) {
    while ((number = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) > 0) {           
        for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            find_object(buffer, &start, &end);
            md5_compute(&buffer[start], end - start);
        }
    }
} else {
    printf("errno %d \n", errno);
}
printf("count = %d \n", count);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: It might take almost 10 seconds to read a 1GB file from disk. When in memory, the OS would keep it there for a while as someone might want to read it again.

Comment: It also depends on the operating system.

Comment: The opened file will be kept in the cache disk (in RAM if you want). You cannot not pilot the caching, you can only flush it.

Comment: @LPs I've put a the main function of my code and my linux version

Comment: I checked my RAM (with system monitor) after the first execution, but I don't see any important RAM usage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can cause a program to run much faster the second time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561362/what-can-cause-a-program-to-run-much-faster-the-second-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the second time, most of your program code and most of the file data are already sitting in the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) (and the kernel won't need any disk I/O to get them into RAM)

You'll likely to observe similar speedup if you run any other program (like `cat` or `wc`) on that big file which reads it sequentially before running your own code.

See also [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html), [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) & the Linux specific [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html) & http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ ; use the [free(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) command before, during, and after running your program to measure memory. Read also about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), since `/proc/` contains a lot of useful pseudo-files describing the kernel state of your machine or your process.

Use also [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html), perhaps as `/usr/bin/time -v`, to benchmark *several times* your program. See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) & [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) ...

Comment: In fact, I can see an additional 1GB of used RAM with free command but not with system monitor application. Thanks :)